# Formatting output using sprintf

Tags: format, output, printf

I have following output with sprintf,

getcmvol:get CM CLI voltage
getcmfirmwareversion: displays CM cli firmware version
getcmserialnum: display CM serial number

I wanted it to output like below,
getcmvol--------------------:          get CM CLI voltage
getcmfirmwareversion----:          displays CM cli firmware version
getcmserialnum------------:          display CM serial number

Pleas Ignore ------- here since this editor is not considering the spaces I have used (hyphen or minus) -----.
printf formats(\t, %3d etc) are not working any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as I understand you problem: You want to output a string field, left-justified with a certain width. To get your a string with this property you could do something like:

```
... = sprintf("%-20s: %d\n", "getcmvol", voltage);
... = sprintf("%-20s: %d\n", "getcmfirmwareversion", version);
...
```

The format strings of `printf` or `sprintf` are explained in detail e.g. [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/). In the above format-string `%-20s` means a 20 chars wide string field, which is left-justified.